# How can I consume web service from business central (Java)?

Tags: java, http, web-services, http-status-code-401, dynamics-business-central

I want to consume Business Central Web service so I can add it to an existing web application.

I have tried:

- Testing with Postman using Authorization header (works)
- Testing SoapUI (works)

But I am getting this error:

```
 com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Unauthorized
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (401Unauthorized
 at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:171)
```

Code:

```java
String webPage = "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/<tenant>/...";
String name = "username";
String password = "password";
String authString = name + ":" + password;

String authEncBytes = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

URL url = new URL(webPage);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

// SOAP Envelope
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.getHeader().detachNode();
envelope.addHeader();
MimeHeaders hd = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncBytes);
SOAPBody soapBodytxaber = envelope.getBody();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("myNamespace", "uri");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem0txa = soapBodytxaber.addChildElement("Read", "myNamespace");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem1txa = soapBodyElem0txa.addChildElement("No", "myNamespace");
soapBodyElem1txa.addTextNode("00000058");

SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = OAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
soapMessage.saveChanges();

SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Okay so after receiving a course, they told me that Basic Authorization is deprecated and they use now OAuth 2...

Thanks for replying

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the user you are trying to authenticate with has a Web Services Access Key.

Then you must use the Web Services Access Key as the password when authenticating.

---

It does also appear that you are missing a `space` after `Basic` in this line of code:

```
hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + authEncBytes);
```

It should probably be

```
hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I already created the key and tested it with postman, accessing with the Authentication on the header manually. It works.
The problem is that it doesn't work on my code, and I don't know if I am missing anything.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes I am really sorry that I didn't put the code correctly, as I've tried already so many things, I didn't change it... However, still didn't do the trick for it. You have my vote anyways